# PHP display long text from PostgreSQL

Tags: php

I have this PHP code that returns and displays the long text after fetching the result from PostgreSQL without line breaks.  How does one display long text from PostgreSQL with line breaks and within PHP framework?

```
for ($i=0; $i<$dataNumRows; $i++) {
//escalation note
$noteSummary = pg_fetch_result($dataQuery,$i,'note_subj');

print " <p> <table width='800'>
<tr><td class='caption' align='left'>Summary:</td><td>$noteSummary</td></tr>
        </table> </p>";
          }
```

Comment: use echo instead of print, and use nl2br($noteSummary); http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the nl2br (New Line to < BR >) method in PHP to convert newline characters to breaklines in HTML. I'm a stickler for readable code so I created the indentation on this bit.

Also, really no point wrapping a TABLE in a paragraph so I removed that.

```
echo "<table width='800'>
          <tr>
              <td class='caption' align='left'>Summary:</td>
              <td>" . nl2br($noteSummary) . "</td>
          </tr>
      </table>";
```

Here is the documentation for further reading: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Comment: Changed my code to your exact code and there's still no line break in display text.  I was hoping by changing to echo from print, this would work, but it doesn't yet.  Any other suggestions?  Thank you.

Comment: Anytime you change the code you are testing, please also update your question so we can review what is happening. Another side note is if you are stripping new lines from the text before inserting it into the database, there is not way to get it back.

Comment: I'll investigate with the DBA whether new lines were stripped from text before inserting it into the database .  That could be the reason because I've tried all kinds of combination using nl2br.

Comment: The carriage returns were inserted back in the database and your solution above works well.  The carriage returns now appear in the final result.  Thank you!  I work for big company so that's why it takes 4 months to finally resolve this issue.